# Adobe Flash stage display specific movie clip frame

Tags: flash, movieclip, stage

I have a movie clip that I am reusing for several flash projects. The movie clip depicts a UI and certain frames naturally show different states of the UI. The current project I'm working on target what is displayed on frame 3 of this movie clip.

I need to add details that are specific to this project. However, when I add the movie clip to the stage it shows the first frame of the clip. Is it possible while editing to have the movie clip be set to a different frame other than 1 while working on the stage?

Answer (score 0):

If you wand to change the MovieClip frame, say you called it movieCLipName .... then use `gotoAndStop()`

`movieCLipName.gotoAndStop(3);`